# Replace null values with previous numbers

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to get previous numbers for the highlighted period, but the below doesn't work.

`If(Len(Request) = 0 , Peek(NewRequest), Request) as NewRequest`

[image: data example]

This is how its looks at the front end in a straight table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqZPf.png)

Comment: I'm clueless as to why when I use a table with Sum(NewRequest) it doesn't display the red highlighted records.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to create the field?

Im using the below code:

```
RawData:
Load 
  *,
  If(Len(Request) = 0 , Peek(NewRequest), Request) as NewRequest
;
Load * Inline [
EmpID, Period  , Employee, Request
AA   , 1/1/2023, Yellow  , 6
AB   , 2/1/2023, Brown   , 16
AC   , 3/1/2023, Pink    , 12
AA   , 2/2/2023, Yellow  , 5
AB   , 2/1/2023, Brown   , 
AC   , 3/1/2023, Pink    , 
];
```

And im getting the below data. As you can see the `NewRequest` column is correctly populated.

[image: data view]

Answer (score 0):

### Update after clarification

In order to see those records in a straight table in the frontend, you'll need to include some dimension field that can uniquely identify each record. Since there are aggregations in the table (`=Sum([Request])` and `=Sum([NewRequest])`) records are essentially just grouped on the available dimension fields. Hence, when Qlik sees two records with `AB, 2/1/2023, Brown` it has nothing to differentiate them, so they're grouped or "collapsed" into one record.

The fix for that is to add a record identifier or, at the least, a more granular key field to differentiate and identify unique records. One of the myriad ways you can achieve this is to use the [`RowNo()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/CounterFunctions/RowNo.htm) to create a new ID field in the data load editor, like so:

```
[RawData New]:
Load
    [Key]
  , [EmpID]
  , [Period]
  , [Employee]
  , [Request]
  , If( IsNull(EmptyIsNull(Request)), ApplyMap('RequestMap', [Key]), [Request]) as NewRequest
  
  , RowNo() as RowID   // <----- Our new record ID field
  
Resident RawData;
```

Then just add that field to your table in the dashboard:

[image: Screen recording GIF of adding a record field to a Qlik Sense table]

If you wanted to do a pure-frontend method, you could try to get fancy with the [Aggr() function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/aggr.htm) and the `NODISTINCT` keyword but it would probably be more hassle than it'd be worth.

---

### Original answer

If you're trying to get the `[Request]` values for the previous `[Period]` + `[Employee]` records, then you have a few options:

## Option 1: `Lookup()` function

You can use the [`Lookup()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/LookUp.htm) to find a value in an already-loaded table, including the current table, given a lookup field, lookup value, and return field.

Here's the script you can use:

```
RawData:
 // Part 3
Load 
  *,
  Coalesce(EmptyIsNull(Request), Lookup(Request, Key, Key)) as NewRequest
;
 // Part 2
Load *,
    AutoNumber(EmpID & '|' & Period) as Key
;
 // Part 1
Load * Inline [
EmpID, Period  , Employee, Request
AA   , 1/1/2023, Yellow  , 6
AB   , 2/1/2023, Brown   , 16
AC   , 3/1/2023, Pink    , 12
AA   , 2/2/2023, Yellow  , 5
AB   , 2/1/2023, Brown   , 
AC   , 3/1/2023, Pink    , 
];
```

What's happening here:

### Part 1

- Load the data.

### Part 2

- Here we use the [`AutoNumber()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/CounterFunctions/autonumber.htm) to create a key field. The function works by returning an incrementing number starting with `1` for a unique concatenation of fields/values. In this case, we get a unique key for each concatenation of the `[EmpID]` and `[Period]` fields. We use `& '|' &` to combine the field values with a pipe `|` symbol as a best practice.

### Part 3

- The [`EmptyIsNull()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/NULLFunctions/EmptyIsNull.htm) is a shorthand for treating empty (`Len([SomeField]) = 0`) values as `Null`. So here, the empty values in the `[Request]` field will be treated as `Null`s.
- The [`Coalesce()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/coalesce.htm) is a shorthand for `If(Not isNull([SomeField]), [SomeField], 'Something else...')`. So basically it's saying "If the `[Request]` field is not null, use that field. If it *is* null, however, use the value returned by `Lookup(...)`."
- The [`Lookup()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/LookUp.htm) is what we use to essentially "look backwards" at the records we've already loaded into our table. So when we use `Lookup(Request, Key, Key)`, what we're saying is "In the `[Key]` field, look up the `[Key]` value for the current record and then return the value you find from the `[Request]` field.

That should all result in Qlik looking for and finding the correct `[Request]` values when they are missing:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik table with new results]

Something to note about the `Lookup()` function is that it can slow down your data load when you have a lot of records. The next option would likely be faster.

## Option 2: `Mapping` load prefix and `ApplyMap()` function

Your other option is to use the [`Mapping` load prefix](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Mapping.htm) and [`ApplyMap()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/MappingFunctions/ApplyMap.htm) to get those previous values.

Here's the script we'll look at:

```
RawData:
 // Part 2
Load *,
    AutoNumber(EmpID & '|' & Period) as Key
;
 // Part 1
Load * Inline [
EmpID, Period  , Employee, Request
AA   , 1/1/2023, Yellow  , 6
AB   , 2/1/2023, Brown   , 16
AC   , 3/1/2023, Pink    , 12
AA   , 2/2/2023, Yellow  , 5
AB   , 2/1/2023, Brown   , 
AC   , 3/1/2023, Pink    , 
];


[RequestMap]:
 // Part 3
Mapping Load Distinct
    [Key]
  , [Request]
Resident RawData
  Where Not IsNull( EmptyIsNull([Request]) )
;


[RawData New]:
 // Part 4
Load
    [Key]
  , [EmpID]
  , [Period]
  , [Employee]
  , [Request]
  , If( IsNull(EmptyIsNull(Request)), ApplyMap('RequestMap', [Key]), [Request]) as NewRequest
Resident RawData;

 // Part 5
Drop Table [RawData];
```

Here's an explanation of things:

### Part 1

- Load the data.

### Part 2

- Here we use the [`AutoNumber()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/CounterFunctions/autonumber.htm) to create a key field. See the explanation in the previous option.

### Part 3

- Here we use the [`Mapping` load prefix](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Mapping.htm) to load a `Mapping` table, which has only two columns, the first of which is the field we "match" on, and the second of which is the field we replace those values with. In our case, our two columns are the `[Key]` field, whose values will be replaced, and the `[Request]` field, whose values will be replacing those in the `[Key]` field. So you can see how it's similar to the `Lookup()` function from the previous option, as we are *looking for* a field to match on and then loading the values from another resulting field.
- Note that we use the `Distinct` keyword as well, which tells Qlik to only load distinct records. That's because a mapping table only needs unique "match-and-replace" options.
- We also use the `Where` clause to filter out the records with empty `[Request]` values. The expression `Where Not IsNull( EmptyIsNull([Request]) )` uses the [`EmptyIsNull()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/NULLFunctions/EmptyIsNull.htm) (explained in the previous option) and the [`IsNull()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/NULLFunctions/IsNull.htm) to check for, and filter out, the records with empty `[Request]` values.

This is what our `[RequestMap]` table looks like underneath the hood:

[image: Screenshot of a Qlik table with results.]

**NOTE: I messed up the above screenshot, just pretend those columns are switched. You want to think of it as "match" field first and then the "replace" field second.**

### Part 4

Here we are loading a new table called `[RawData New]` -- the important part of this table load is this expression here:

`If( IsNull(EmptyIsNull(Request)), ApplyMap('RequestMap', [Key]), [Request]) as NewRequest`

Here's what it's doing:

- First, in our `If()` statement, we check to see if the `[Request]` field is empty/null for the current record. If it is, we use the [`ApplyMap()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/MappingFunctions/ApplyMap.htm) to "map over" the values of the `[Key]` field using the `[RequestMap]` table we created previously using the `Mapping` load. So basically Qlik will take the `[Key]` value for the current field, search the first column of the `[RequestMap]` table for that value, and if it finds it, it will return the value in the second column of the `[RequestMap]` table. If it doesn't find a matching value in the first column, it will just return `Null`. If, however, the `[Request]` field is *not* empty/null for the current record, it will simply return the value found in the `[Request]` field.

### Part 5

- Here we [`Drop`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/drop-table.htm) the original `[RawData]` table since we no longer need it -- we now have the `[RawData New]` table that has all of our data, including the new `[NewRequest]` field.

This should result in what we want:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik table with the results]

Comment: it doesn't work in a table when I sum Newrequest as an expression.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? And when you say "table" are you talking about a table in the data model or are you talking about a table in the dashboard? Did you follow my steps and get the resulting table shown in the screenshot above? Are you trying to achieve this in the dashboard only and not the Data Load Editor? Perhaps edit your original question to include some screenshots of exactly what you've tried and the incorrect results you're seeing.

Comment: It works perfectly at the backend. And, yes ultimately it has to be done in the dashboard. I attached a snippet of how it looks in a straight table.

Comment: Gotcha, just updated my answer to include new guidance!